# If condition using object

Tags: object, if-statement

This is for Javascript

I have not seen this before.  The if statement includes simply an object

- if(grid && grid.length > 10) ...

where "grid" is the object.  Is the way it's coded here a typical usage, being there's no test for a true or false condition.  Maybe it's just asking if the object exists or not?

Seems to work as otherwise expected.  I don't know if the object as a standalone condition is doing anything at all.

Comment: which language is that? Please tag it correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A non boolean value can be considered falsy in JS, and the sample you're provided is a perfectly legitimate check for the presence of grid before continuing.

[https://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/#:~:text=Yes%2C%20in%20JavaScript%2C%20several%20non,will%20be%20treated%20as%20false](https://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/#:%7E:text=Yes%2C%20in%20JavaScript%2C%20several%20non,will%20be%20treated%20as%20false).

Comment: who said that the code is in JS? And sitepoint is not an authoritative source of JS documentation